# "A challenge to X" vs. "a challenge for X"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Nile countries are facing tremendous challenges for food security,...

Should I use "a challenge for" or "a challenge to" in the above sentence?

Comment: Why try to let one puny little preposition do all your work? _Nile countries are facing tremendous challenges with regard to food security, ..._

Comment: A lot depends on whether the countries currently have food security but are afraid of losing it (in which case you could say "Nile countries face tremendous challenges to their future food security") or whether they currently lack it and are desperate to achieve it (in which case you could say "Nile countries face tremendous challenges in their ongoing efforts to achieve food security"). In either case, the only way "a challenge for" might come in handy is if you flipped the whole thing around: "Lack of food security poses a continuing challenge for Nile countries."

Answer (score 2):

"Challenges for food security" sounds like "food security" is some sort of entity or organization that is facing challenges, while what you're trying to say is that it is the Nile countries that are being challenged.

I would go with "challenges in the field of food security" or "challenges to their food security infrastructure," just to be clear.